# When and how can we start forgetting about non-retina display iPhones and iPod Touches?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod-touch

Now more than one year passed since a retina display device appeared. Does anyone know some numbers how many users still suffer under the low-resolution devices? How long do they use their iPhones or iPods until they realize that a retina display is so much better?

I'm sick of having to create every graphic two times, trashing the binary with all these low-resolution files. I wonder if anyone has stopped supporting low resolution hardware without a big loss.

And: If I wanted to stop supporting low resolution devices, what kind of settings in the info.plist must I make? And what would happen if a low-res device still installs my retina-only app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can at least wait for Apple to stop providing iOS updates to low-resolution devices (i.e. iPhone 3G S) since it is capable of running iOS 5

Answer (score 2):

Why do people still use IE 6? or why do some people still have Windows XP? Simply b/c they can't afford new ones. Money is to blame. There is no simple answer as to when should you stop supporting certain technology. In the technology world you should usually wait for a big company (like Facebook) to stop supporting certain devices. Only those big sharks can force people to switch.

If you want your users to be happy and want your software to be great you should always support all available devices/versions if possible. Little work for you is a big benefit for your users.

In the end you don't have to do anything you don't want to. But your software will resemble it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its not possible right now as it isnt yet supported [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3).

But releasing your app with a iOS deployment target of iOS 4.2 may reduce the number of non-retina display users to a great extent.

And the main reason for users not switching to new devices is explained perfectly in the previous answer. :)